# Как спарсить следующие значения из xml?

Tags: delphi, xml, delphi-xe

Работаю с xml файлом через стандартный TXMLDocument.
В файле встретился Node следующего вида:

```
<Txt>
    bit=3
    aaa=020, 120, 220, 210, 200, 021, 121
    bbb=221, 211, 201, 022, 122, 222, 212, 202 
    ccc=000
</Txt>
```

К этим bit, aaa, bbb, ccc можно как-то достучаться стандартными средствами TXMLDocument или для него это просто текст и нужно парсить как IniFile?

Comment: Это просто текст. Парсить нужно вручную.

Comment: Я так и думал, очень жаль, но надежда теплилась, нужно было спросить) Спарсил через TMemIniFile